# Choose where to insert my youtube video

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api

I have this code which I found on Stack a few weeks ago.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
// I added the video size here in case you wanted to modify it more easily
var vidWidth = 300; // 425;
var vidHeight = 200; // 344;
     var obj = '<object width="' + vidWidth + '" height="' + vidHeight + '">' + '<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/[vid]&hl=en&fs=1">' + '</param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param ' + 'name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><em' + 'bed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/[vid]&hl=en&fs=1" ' + 'type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" ' + 'allowfullscreen="true" width="' + vidWidth + '" ' + 'height="' + vidHeight + '"></embed></object> ';

$('.posthold:contains("youtube.com/watch")').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var vid = that.html().match(/v=([\w\-]+)/g); // end up with v=oHg5SJYRHA0

     that.html(function(i, h) {
        return h.replace(/(http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch\?v=+\S+\S?)/g, '');
    });

    if (vid.length) {
        $.each(vid, function(i) {
            that.append(obj.replace(/\[vid\]/g, this.replace('v=', '')));
        });
    }
});
 });
 </script>
```

It works great at embeding videos from url's.  But I have a small problem with it that I have been trying to solve but i keep breaking the code.

Basically I have the following div setup

```
<div class="grid_10 alpha omega posthold" >
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="grid_2 alpha">
    <img src="/images/no-image/logo_default.jpg" width="100" height="100" />
    </a></div>
  <div class="grid_8 omega">
    <h1>Some Name Here</h1>
    <p>Some Comment here</p>

  </div>
</div>

 </div>
```

Im trying to get the video to appear directly after the closing paragraph tag where it says some comment here.  The user enters the video as part of a post.  I store the post in a database and when I pull the post out I swap the url from youtube to the embed code.  This is a repeating div so there maybe many instances that a video appears.  Is this even possible.  At the minute the video appears after the last closing div tag.

Comment: your HTML is malformed. `</a>` `<--` where does this come from???

Comment: @ahren sorry thats a mistake.  The div setup is   actually a bit more complicated than that.  I just stripped out a load of html.  must of missed that one

Comment: var that = $(this);?? Hate to be your successor and have to edit files like this.